# Function in R that returns first word in a sentence that is having a length which is an even number & also longest even word

Tags: r

This function should return the longest even word(string) that is the first occurence of a string with maximal even number length.If there are no even length it should return 00.

Constraints-
The sentence string consist of spaces & the sentence range is  between 1 to  10^5.

For ex- 
Sentence 1-"Time & tide waits for none".Here , even characters are time & tide & none with 4  letters. But,time occurs first so time should be displayed.
Sentence 2-" Tit for tat".In this sentence no even so it  this should return 00.
Sentence 3-"Eyes are mirror of person's thoughts"  here , thoughts is the greatest even word amongst even words eyes, mirror.

Comment: Can you show what you already tried to do?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What about your approach didn't work?

Comment: I tried getting even function but it fails when I try getting the first occuring largest even function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the popular stringr and dplyr libraries.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(
  sentence = c(
    "Time & tide waits for none",
    " Tit for tat",
    "Eyes are mirror of person's thoughts",
    "Some Other Sentence",
    "Odd sentences failure"
  )
)

df <- df %>%
  # Split the sentence and store it in a new column
  mutate(split_sentence = str_split(sentence," ")) %>%
  # Do the next step row wise because we will be dealing with a vector of vectors
  rowwise() %>%
  # Keep only words that have a remainder of 0 when divided by 2 (str_length modulo 2)
  mutate(split_sentence = list(split_sentence[str_length(split_sentence) %% 2 == 0])) %>%
  # Only keep non-null strings !""
  mutate(split_sentence = list(split_sentence[str_length(split_sentence) > 0])) %>%
  # Find the first word with the longest length
  mutate(split_sentence = list(split_sentence[which.max(str_length(split_sentence))])) %>%
  # Keep only the first word left in the vector or return NA if none left
  mutate(first_even = first(split_sentence)) %>%
  # Ungroup because we don't need to work rowwise anymore
  ungroup() %>%
  # Convert any NA values to "00" per question
  mutate(first_even = ifelse(is.na(first_even),"00",first_even)) %>%
  select(-split_sentence)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
#   sentence                             first_even
#   <chr>                                <chr>     
# 1 Time & tide waits for none           Time      
# 2 " Tit for tat"                       00        
# 3 Eyes are mirror of person's thoughts person's  
# 4 Some Other Sentence                  Sentence  
# 5 Odd sentences failure                00
```

In your description you said that `thoughts` would be the longest word but my alogrithm found that `person's` was just as long. If you want to remove the appostrophe you can figure out how to do that using the `str_remove_all()` function. I'll leave that for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Adam.This helps.I have one more query if you could help me with that.Instead of manually entering the sentence.Can't we enter the sentence in the format like- sentence string consists of spaces & characters in the ranges ascii [a-z,A-Z] only?Consider a string ,sentence of space centered words where each word is a substring consisting of english alphabetic letters only?

Comment: You can definitely do this. Check out `stringr::str_remove_all("This is a string. In addition, this is a string!","[^A-Za-z ]+")` which removes all characters that are not between A-Z or a-z or space. Throw this in before you split the string and bam.