# Find the longest even word in a sentence, if two or more words have same length, then the first occurring word must be returned

Tags: r, string

I am trying out this problem, wherein I need to find the longest even word in a given input sentence and if two or more words are longest even length words, then the first occurring word must be returned.

For ex: if 'this is a great song'
the function should return 'this' as it's the longest first appearing even length word in the sentence.

This question was asked before and answered using dplyr, 
[Function in R that returns first word in a sentence that is having a length which is an even number & also longest even word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876343/function-in-r-that-returns-first-word-in-a-sentence-that-is-having-a-length-whic)

I wish to try using my code:

below is my code:

```
sentence <- function(ip_sen) {
  sentence_split <- strsplit(ip_sen, split = ' ')[[1]] #splitting the sentence into words
  word_lengths_vector <- vector() #empty vector to store even length words

  for (word in sentence_split) {
    word_split <- strsplit(word, split = '')[[1]] #splitting each word
    word_length <- length(word_split)

    if (word_length %% 2 == 0) { # checking if the word is even
      word_lengths_vector <- c(word_lengths_vector, word) #adding such words to the empty vector
    }
  }

  for (w in 1:(length(word_lengths_vector)-1)) { #finding the longest word
    if (nchar(word_lengths_vector[w]) >  nchar(word_lengths_vector[w+1])) {
      word_lengths_vector <- word_lengths_vector[-(w+1)] #removing smaller length words
    }
  }

  word_lengths_vector[1] #returning the first word in the vector which will be the first occurring longest word
}

sentence('this is a great song')
```

But I am getting below error:

> Error in if (nchar(word_lengths_vector[w]) > nchar(word_lengths_vector[w +
>       : 
>         missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Could someone let me know how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could simplify the function a bit

```
sentence <- function(ip_sen) {
   #split the text on whitespace
   all_words <- strsplit(ip_sen, " ")[[1]]
   #Get number of characters in each word
   all_chars <- nchar(all_words)
   #Filter only those words with even characters and select the first max
   all_words[which.max(all_chars[all_chars %% 2 == 0])]
}

sentence('this is a great song')
#[1] "this"

sentence('What is your complete name?')
#[1] "complete"
```